# HTML Element location relative to screen

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the location of a div element relative to the screen.
I read every where and still can't find a solution to this, my code currently is:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('pi');
var myElement2 = document.body;

alert (myElement.offsetTop + ',' + myElement.offsetLeft);
alert (myElement2.offsetTop + ',' + myElement2.offsetLeft);
alert (window.screenX);
```

All i get is 8,8 for my div element which is not really the location.

HTML code:

`<body>
    <div id=pi >fffddd</div>
 </body>`

Comment: What is the actual position should be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/ZPZQ4/  doesn't have any code related to your question...

Comment: Looks like your element is at 8,8 in an iframe - it is in the jsfiddle. If you know that is the case, you'll need to get the position of the iframe using similar code and add those values.

Comment: @Mamun should be the location relative to my screen, the div appears in the middle of my screen and my screen certainly not 16x16 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the left edge of the browser is the left edge of the body and all of the difference between window.innerHeight and window.outerHeight is above the body you can get a lot closer to what you are asking for. There are additional assumptions being made here with regards to multi-display setups.

```
xPos = myElement.offsetLeft + window.screenX;
yPos = myElement.offsetTop + window.screenY + window.outerHeight -
```

window.innerHeight;

```js
let myElement = document.body,
    xPos = myElement.offsetLeft + window.screenX,
    yPos = myElement.offsetTop + window.screenY + window.outerHeight -
 window.innerHeight;

alert ( xPos + ',' + yPos );
```